# Remove Light Spots from Photo & improve gold effect

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I want to

1. remove the light spot from the apple below, and
2. Additionally, I want to remove all the black parts, that the apple looks just golden. What is the best way to do this? I tried the following:

a) Healing Brush Tool and Spot Healing Tool. This worked not too bad. But are there better solutions?

b) I also tried the "Curves" adjustment layer, masked out the light spot and tried to darken it. This doesnt look great...

Additional question:
How can I improve the overall gold effect of this picture?

Many thanks for your ideas and for your support

[image]

[image]

Comment: You hopefully realize. that it is the *variation of tones* which conveys any "gold" appearance. If the light and dark areas are removed, what is left is, essentially, a flat yellow apple - not "gold". Maybe that's what you want. However, there are easier ways to get just a flat yellow apple shape.

Comment: The effect @oneprivate made demonstrates why removing the glossy reflection is a bad idea. If you want to improve the "gold effect". Removing the reflection of the source light is the opposite of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Environment reflections make it look metallic. A camera and photorealistic 3D model rendering make the image contain right reflections automatically if you have rich enough environment and good light conditions. A capable artist can imagine them. The rest of us need also some luck.

In your case the environment unfortunately contains too bright lights. You can wipe it off by using the smudge brush. The brush strokes should be short, have a low strength % and they must be directed like you polished the apple surface. Fade possible caused too sharp borders with blur. The result:

[image]

Removing all glosses and (fake or true) dark environment reflections, like you seem to want, makes it look like it's sprayed with matte paint. Such effect can be got from graphics programs easily - like this revolved shape:

[image]

Making it look 3D is based on brightness variations (shading). They cannot be removed if it must look a 3D shape.

It may look gold paint if it has a well selected color, but forget it, if it must be also metallic.

Comment: Good answer, and also demonstrates why removing the highlight is counterproductive. Not that it looks like a stain instead of a shiny apple. :(

Comment: Many thanks to all the helpful answers - learned a lot today. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

> How can I improve the overall gold effect of this picture?

This is only a suggestion. Probably a warmer tone on the image is a bit better.

I exaggerated a bit the editing on a red channel curve, just to show the change.

If the color is too yellowish could look like brass.

[image]